# Call method when specific division of integer is reached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, operators, monodevelop

I am programming a video game, and in it, I would like to call a method that adds a player bonus life for every 2,000 points scored.  I have no idea what operator(s) to use for such a thing.

```
If (score is divisible by 2000, each increment){
 DoSomething();
 }
```

I'm not even sure if I'm asking this question correctly.  Basically when the player scores 2,000pts, 4,000pts, 6,000pts, etc, I want to give him/her a bonus life by calling a method.  I already have the method created; I was just wondering how I can apply the conditions that call it.

I tried using this:

```
public int bonusTarget = 2000;
paddle = GameObject.Find("Paddle").GetComponent<Paddle>();

if(score >= bonusTarget){
            paddle.Bonus();
            bonusTarget += 2000;
            }
```

but, it awarded more than one bonus life each increment.  I need to award the bonus life only one time for each 2,000pts

Answer (score 1):

"score is divisible by 2000"

```
if (score % 2000 == 0) DoSomething()
```

If You need to track score use property instead of varilable eg.:

```
private int _score;
public int Score 
{
    get 
    {
         return _score;
    }
    set 
    {
        var a = Math.Floor(_score / 2000)
        var b = Math.Floor(value / 2000)
        if (a < b) DoSomething(); 
        _score = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `if(score is divisible by 2000)` check inside the `DoSomething()` method.

There's no reason to keep this outside the method that increases the bonus lives, in the dozens of possible code paths that increase the score.  You need ONE CENTRAL location that the score increases, and checks various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a centralized location to add to the score, like this:

```
public void AddToScore(int points)
{
    score += points;
    if (score >= bonusTarget)
    {
        bonusTarget += 2000;
        paddle.Bonus();
    }
}
```

I switched the two lines inside the conditional block in case `paddle.Bonus()` tries adding points itself, which could cause issues, possibly even infinite recursion.

If you make it so you always add to the score using this method, you can add any special handling you want. You might also want to write a `ResetScore()` and a `GetScore()` so you never access `score` directly elsewhere in your code.